# How to collapse a categorical variable into less elements in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a categorical variable such like:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-sample(c("I", "IA", "IB", "II", "IIB", "IIC", "III", "IIID", "IIIF", "XA", "XB", "XC"), 
    100, TRUE)
table(x, exclude=NULL)

#    x
#   I   IA   IB   II  IIB  IIC  III IIID IIIF   XA   XB   XC <NA> 
#   5   12    9    7    9   11    6    8    6   12    9    6    0
```

My question is how to easily collapse `x` into four elements, e.g. I, II, III and X? E.g. combining I, IA, IB into I etc.

Comment: `factor(gsub('[^I]', '', x), strrep('I', 1:3))` but I think this is a simple case for what you really need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if your categorical variables aren't grouped by such patterns, you can specify a mapping using `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
y <- case_when(x %in% c("I", "IA", "IB") ~ "I", #or whatever conditions you want
               x %in% c("II", "IIA", "IIB") ~ "II", #as above
               TRUE ~ "III")
table(y)

  I  II III 
 33  24  43
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
table(gsub("[^I]", "", x))

#   I  II III 
#  33  34  33
```

This replaces all characters that are not `I` from your vector and then computes its frequencies.

Or, to change `x`:

```
x <- gsub("[^I]", "", x)
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe my question is not very clear but I may have XA, XB, XC as well. I will update it to be clear..

Comment: I mean this answer still will work `table(gsub("[^IX]", "", x))`

Comment: Do `gsub('[^IX]+', '', x)` for the new question

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** after question has been updated.

The `forcats` package has some handy functions to deal with factors.

The `fct_collapse()` function can be used to collapse factor levels into *manually* defined groups:

```
y <- forcats::fct_collapse(x, 
                           I   = c("I", "IA", "IB"),
                           II  = c("II", "IIB", "IIC"),
                           III = c("III", "IIID", "IIIF"),
                           X   = c("XA", "XB", "XC"))
table(y, exclude=NULL)
```

> ```
> y
>   I  II III   X 
>  26  27  20  27
> ```

The `fct_relabel()` function *automatically* relabels factor levels and collapses as necessary. It takes a function that is applied to each level which accepts one character argument and returns a character vector of the same length as its input. The function used here extracts a sequence of `I` or `X` characters from the beginning

```
y <- forcats::fct_relabel(factor(x), stringr::str_extract, pattern = "^I+|X+")
table(y, exclude=NULL)
```

> ```
> y
>   I  II III   X 
>  26  27  20  27
> ```